# Laravel: one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, model

There is such a structure:
There is a model book (`Book`) and model systems age restrictions (`Rars`).
One book can be only one rars, but on one rars can refer a lot of books. That is, the relationship - one to many?
The model Book:

```
class Book extends Model
{
    public function rars()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Rars');
    }
}
```

The model Rars:

```
class Rars extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }
}
```

In migration Book:

```
$table->integer('rars_id');
$table->foreign('rars_id')->references('id')->on('rars');
```

Run code:

```
$book->rars()->save(\App\Rars::where('eternal_name', 'no_limits')->first());
(Rars with this eternal_name, guaranteed to exist)
```

And this return:

```
[BadMethodCallException]                                            
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should explain clearly what are your trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation, for updating 'Belongs To' relationships you should use `associate` method.
So i think this will work:

```
$book->rars()->associate(\App\Rars::where('eternal_name', 'no_limits')->first());
$book->save();
```

For more information you can read here, https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to edit Rars with an Instance of Book. Make an instance of Rars instead. if you have the book id, do as following.

```
$book = new Book();
$book = $book->find($bookId);
$rars = new Rars();
$rars = $rars->find($book->rars_id);

/* Update data */

$rars->save();
```